# Delete everything before a pattern

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I'm trying to clean a text file.

I want to delete everything start before the first 12 numbers.

```
1:0:135103079189:0:0:2:0::135103079189:000011:00
A:908529896240:0:10250:2:0:1:
603307102606:0:0:1:0::01000::M
```

Output desired:

```
135103079189:0:0:2:0::135103079189:000011:00
908529896240:0:10250:2:0:1:
603307102606:0:0:1:0::01000::M
```

Here's my command but seems not working.

```
sed '/:\([0-9]\{12\}\)/d' t.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `d` command in `sed` will delete entire line on matching the given regex, you need to use `s` command to search and replace only part of line... however, for given problem, `sed` is not suitable as it doesn't support non-greedy regex

you can use `perl` instead

```
$ perl -pe's/^.*?(?=\d{12}:)//' ip.txt
135103079189:0:0:2:0::135103079189:000011:00
908529896240:0:10250:2:0:1:
603307102606:0:0:1:0::01000::M
```

- `.*?` match zero or more characters as minimally as possible

  - `(?=\d{12}:)` only if it is followed by 12-digits ending with `:`
- use `perl -i -pe` for in-place editing

some possible corner cases

```
$ # this is matching part of field
$ echo 'foo:123:abc135103079189:23:603307102606:1' | perl -pe's/^.*?(?=\d{12}:)//'
135103079189:23:603307102606:1
$ # this is not matching 12-digit field at end of line
$ echo 'foo:123:135103079189' | perl -pe's/^.*?(?=\d{12}:)//'
foo:123:135103079189

$ # so, add start/end of line matching cases and restrict 12-digits to whole field
$ echo 'foo:123:abc135103079189:23:603307102606:1' | perl -pe 's/^(?:.*?:)?(?=\d{12}(:|$))//'
603307102606:1
$ echo 'foo:123:135103079189' | perl -pe's/^(?:.*?:)?(?=\d{12}(:|$))//'
135103079189
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk --re-interval 'match($0,/[0-9]{12}/){print substr($0,RSTART)}' Input_file
```

Since I have OLD version of `awk` so I am using `--re-interval` you could remove it in case you have new version of it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/[0-9]\{12\}/\n&/;s/.*\n//p' file
```

We only want to print specific lines so use the `-n` option to turn off automatic printing. If a line contains a 12 digit number, insert a newline before it. Remove any characters before and including a newline and print the result.

If you want to print lines that do not contain a 12 digit number as is, use:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{12\}/\n&/;s/.*\n//' file
```

The crux of the problem is to identify the start of a multi-character string, insert a unique marker and delete all characters before and including the unique marker. As sed uses the newline to delimit lines, only the user can introduce newlines into the pattern space and as a result, newlines will always be unique.

Comment: Once again you introduced a `sed` solution that I failed to come up with. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Taking the nice answer from @Sundeep, in case you would like to use `grep` or `pcregrep` (macOS/BSD) you could give a try to:

```
$ grep -oP '^(?:.*?:)?(?=\d{12})\K.*' file
```

or

```
$ pcregrep -o '^(?:.*?:)?(?=\d{12})\K.*' file
```

The `\K` will ignore everything after the pattern

Answer (score 0):

Alternative thoughts  - I almost think your data is too dirty for a quick sed fix but if generally it's all similar to your sample set of data then certainly pick one of the answers with sed etc. However if you wanted to be more particular about it you could build up a set of commands to ensure the values. I like doing this for debugging and when speed isn't urgent.

Take this tiny sample of code, you could do this other ways but I'm getting the value for each part of the string and I know the order because it contiguous. You could then set up controls on which parts to keep and such as it builds out say a new string per line. Overwrought for sure, but sometimes that is a better long term approach.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line ;do
        IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
        for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)) ;do
                echo "part : ${array[$i]}"
        done
done < "test_data.txt"
```

You could then build the data back up how you wanted and more easily understand what's happening every step of the way ..

```
part : 1
part : 0
part : 135103079189
part : 0
part : 0
part : 2
part : 0
part :
part : 135103079189
part : 000011
part : 00
part : A
part : 908529896240
part : 0
```